# DAX query to calculate the number of months past in the current finyear

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to write a measure that gives me the number of months past in the current financial year.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be referenced to any particular data structure or just the true current, i.e. `today`?

Comment: Just the current date or compared to current month. So for instance its its been 4 months to date this in this current finyear.

Answer (score 0):

The following DAX can do if you just need to compare to a particular date:

```
Months past = 
VAR fiscal_date = TODAY()
VAR fiscal_month = 7
VAR fiscal_year = IF(MONTH(fiscal_date) < fiscal_month, YEAR(fiscal_date) -1, YEAR(fiscal_date))
RETURN DATEDIFF(DATE(fiscal_year, fiscal_month, 1), fiscal_date, MONTH)
```

Where `fiscal_date` is the date you want to compare to, e.g. `TODAY()`.

`fiscal_month` is the month number that your fiscal year starts. (You may need to change it according to your need)

`fiscal_year` is to work out the year of current fiscal year.

---

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: Hi @sth3 does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.